I'm consistently facing error org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
It's saying org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service': Error creating bean with name 'productService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo': Error creating bean with name 'productRepo' defined in com.example.ecomwebsitejava.repo.ProductRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.example.ecomwebsitejava.repo.ProductRepo.searchproduct(java.lang.String); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.ecomwebsitejava.repo.ProductRepo.searchproduct(java.lang.String)
Controller layer code - I have already given annotations autowired, Restcontroller
 @GetMapping("/products/search")
  public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> searchproduct(@RequestParam String keyword)
  {
      List<Product> products=service.searchproduct(keyword);
      return new ResponseEntity<>(products,HttpStatus.OK);
  }

Service layer code - I have already given service
public List<Product> searchproduct(String keyword){
            return repo.searchproduct(keyword);
    }

``
Repo layer code - I have already given Repository annotation
public interface ProductRepo extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE"+
   "LOWER(p.name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%' , :keyword, '%')")
    List<Product> searchproduct(String keyword);
}
 


You are missing a whitespace after WHERE. Your qery now reads SELECT p FROM Product p WHERELOWER(p.name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%' , :keyword, '%') due to the missing space. You are also missing a closing ) at the end of the query for the LOWER function.

There is a missing ) in the query and a missing space between WHERE and LOWER clauses.
If you read the exception, the issue is not in the autowiring, but in query validation. It should be:
@Query("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE " 
    + " LOWER(p.name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%' , :keyword, '%')) ")

Try it and please check all the stack trace.

You are missing a space after the WHERE and a closing clammer ')'. To avoid these exceptions in the future, I would recommend using text blocks instead of string concatenation.
public interface ProductRepo extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer> {
    @Query("""
        SELECT p FROM Product p
        WHERE LOWER(p.name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%' , :keyword, '%'))
    """)
    List<Product> searchproduct(String keyword);
}


Thankyou it's working

I can see 2 things wrong with your query a missing space and a missing ) at the end. You can either fix the query or replace it by a finder method.
Fix query
Fix the query by adding a space after WHERE and adding a closing ) for the LOWER function. As you are probably on a newer Java you should also use textblocks, those are easier and less error prone. Using text blocks makes the query more readable as well.
@Query("""
   SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE 
   LOWER(p.name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%' , :keyword, '%'))
""")

Use a finder method
You can write a finder method which does the same, without having to write a query yourself. You can use the Containing and IgnoreCase keywords for that, which are understood by Spring Data.
List<Product> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String keyword);

These query methods and generation are particularly useful for simple cases like this.

Thankyou it's working
